# Graphview library is not displaying y-axis properly with human rounding set to false?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am using a graphview library from github, simply named Graphview.

I have dates as x-axis and prices on the y-axis. I get the data from an api but when I set human rounding to false the y-axis goes crazy and adds way to many values: [Picture of it happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8oY9.png)

Now if i turn on human rounding, the y-values are fixed but the dates are displayed weirdly: [Picture of that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7NNH.png)

When I rotate the device then there is no problem, I don't know what is wrong please help.

Code:

```
     @Override
     public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<GraphObject>> loader, 
     ArrayList<GraphObject> graphObjects) {

    if (graphObjects != null && !graphObjects.isEmpty()) {
        ArrayList<GraphObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(graphObjects);
        List<DataPoint> list = getDataPoint(graphObjects);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<> 
        (list.toArray(new DataPoint[1]));
        Log.e("Message", objects.get(0).getclose());
        graphView.addSeries(series);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLyy");
        graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new 
        DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(this,simpleDateFormat));
        graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3);

        graphView.getViewport().setMinX(list.get(0).getX());
        graphView.getViewport().setMaxX(list.get(list.size()-1).getX());
        graphView.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
    }

}

     private List<DataPoint> getDataPoint(ArrayList<GraphObject> graphObjects) {
    List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (GraphObject object : graphObjects) {
        String close_string = object.getclose();
        String string_time = object.getMtime();
        long time = Long.parseLong(string_time);
        time = time * 1000;
        Double close = Double.parseDouble(close_string);
        Date dateObject = new Date(time);
        dataPoints.add(new DataPoint(dateObject, close));
    }
    return dataPoints;
}
```

Comment: please crop your pictures so that they show only the needed grpah and not the whole smartphone screen.

Answer (score 0):

`DataPoint[] dataPoint = new DataPoint[total_count];
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoint);`

> set these attributes

- graph.setDrawDataPoints(true)
- graph.setMaxX(date2.getTime())
- graph.setXAxisBoundsManual(false)
- graph.addSeries(series);

> to formet lable

```
`graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter() {
               @Override
               public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
                   if (isValueX) {
                       // show normal x values
                       Date date1 = IRoidAppHelper.parseTime(Helper.parseTime(productPriceData.getdate(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", "dd-MM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy");
                       String dateString =Helper.parseTime(date1.getTime(), "dd/MM");
                       return dateString;
                   } else {
                       // show currency for y values
                       return super.formatLabel(value, isValueX);
                   }
               }
           });`
```